# Show time of merge for a file in git

Tags: git

For a single file, can I get the time it was merged into the current branch in git?
I would like to find out when the file was merged (I can see only the commit time in `git log`, who did that merge and possibly other files within the same merge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git log --first-parent --merges -1 -- path/to/it
```

and to get the other files

```
git rev-list --first-parent --merges -1 @ -- path/to/it \
| git show -m --name-only --stdin
```

or

```
git show -m --name-only $(git rev-list --first-parent --merges -1 @ -- path/to/it)
```

Comment: Tried `git log --first-parent --merges -1 -m --name-only -- path/to/it` - seems it does not change the output, however

Comment: You'll have to drop the path, but in doing so, your `git log` may pick another commit (closer to `HEAD`).  So, instead, find the hash ID with the first command first, then run `git log -m --name-only -1 <commit-id>` (or replace `-1` with `--no-walk`, which is actually kind of nicer but takes more typing). If you don't want the full `git log` output from the first step, use `git rev-list`, which is like `git log` except that it prints only the hash ID. (Or you can use `--format=%H`, which directs `git log` to print just the hash ID; I prefer `git rev-list` here myself as it's more efficient.)

Comment: Oh.  It only shows the one file. Fixed.  Thanks @torek.